# Adding an Activity in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-activity

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 2.2.2 and the ability to add an activity during the Create New Project quick start is no longer available. Where/how can I add my first activity in to a project?

Thank you!

Comment: File->New->Activity isn't available? I have installed Android Studio 2.2.2 and it is available yet.

Comment: No, File > New doesn't have an option for Activity. The options I see are Project, Project from Existing Sources, Project from Version Control, Module, Module from Existing Sources, File, Directory, HTML File, and Resource Bundle.

Comment: so, you can create new activity by adding new java class, xml file and new activity info in your AndroidManifest.xml, please see docs: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: I can't follow those instructions because it's not providing me the same options. I opened an old project that I had created under a previous version and I don't get the Activity option under New when right clicking the app folder. In fact when I create new projects with the 2.2.2 version, it doesn't create an app folder or many of the folders it used to. Maybe there was something that I did wrong during the install? I don't know what would cause this.

Comment: strange isuue. so, try to reinstall Andorid Studio, I hope it help you

Comment: I've already tried that as well as switching back to 2.2.1. The weird thing was when I switched back to 2.2.1, it was doing the same thing (not providing me options to add activities) when it never did before. I downloaded 2.2.2 on my laptop which has a difficult time running the application with good performance, but it behaves 'correctly' allowing me to add activities. This has me thinking that when I've uninstalled it prior on my desktop, some setting or some such were left behind which is the problem. I'm working to completely uninstall including any settings and reinstalling.

Comment: This seems to have worked and I reinstalled the 2.2.1 version. Wish I knew what had occurred to make this happen in the first place though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are some issues with latest 2.2.2 version of Android Studio, especially on Linux systems. Please delete/uninstall existing version and download 2.2.1 from [tools.android.com](http://tools.android.com).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in android.2.2.3 "new activity" not listed,  but a simple restart of android studio solves it. I restarted android studio and now it shows new activity option..